# Is an automatic git stash pop happening?

Tags: git, github

I did a `git stash push` before changing branches from `feature` to `main` as there were uncommitted changes.

But once I changed back from `main` to `feature`, the uncommitted changes automatically applied on `feature` branch without me doing a `git stash pop`.

But when I did a `git stash list`, it still contained the uncommitted changes in it.

Could someone explain what's going on, on the surface level it seems like an automatic `git stash pop` but looks like that's not what it is.

NOTE: I changed to `main` to do a `git pull`. Just putting it out there if it's important.

Comment: No, there is no automatic pop happening. Are you sure you haven't committed those changes before? If you run `git status` are they shown under "Changes not staged for commit"?

Comment: @knittl, that is exactly what happened. I didn't realize that. This was because the difference between the stashed changes and current commit in `feature` was the difference in content of existing files rather than new files. Thank you.

Comment: Can you share the exact commands that you were executing, Leon?

Comment: it was `git stash push` -> `git checkout main` -> `git pull` -> '`git checkout feature`. In case, you didn't get what I said, basically you were right when I ran `git status`, everything was as it is

Comment: This sequence of commands will not auto-pop (or auto-apply) your stash. No idea, how you ended up with unstaged changes in your working tree and in your stash